# Use a hierarchy of nodes in slurm to switch to preemptible when on-demand is full

Tags: cloud, slurm, preemption

Suppose I prepaid for a finite number of on-demand GPUs. When those get full, I'd like to have my jobs get sent to pre-emptible GPUs.

Is there a way to effect this in slurm? I'm imagining a hierarchy of resources or nodes so that when one resource is completely in use, it falls back to the next one.